# Recaptcha timeout and Validation Error Message on Form Display

Tags: sitecore-forms

I followed the below post to create a custom field for Recaptcha in Sitecore forms- https://dev.to/chandra_kodi/sitecore-google-recaptcha-v3-5d18

I am trying to validate it, but I am getting timeout or duplicate response from Google recaptcha as it is expiring in two mins. How to handle this. I tried `expired-callback` but not working. Also, I am validating server side recaptcha but I am not sure how I can display the recaptcha error message on the sitecore form? How to send the validation result to `FormSubmitContext`

```
    protected override bool Execute(string data, FormSubmitContext formSubmitContext)
    {

        Assert.ArgumentNotNull(formSubmitContext, nameof(formSubmitContext));

        if (formSubmitContext.HasErrors)
        {
    }
```

My HTML and Code :-

```
<div id="inline-badge"></div>
<input id="@Html.IdFor(m => Model.Value)" name="@Html.NameFor(m => Model.Value)" class="@Model.CssClass" type="hidden" value="" />
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=explicit&onload=onRecaptchaLoadCallback"></script>

<script>
    function onRecaptchaLoadCallback() {
        var clientId = grecaptcha.render('inline-badge', {
            'sitekey': '@Model.ApiKey',
            'badge': 'bottomright',
            'size': 'invisible',
            'expired-callback': expCallback
        });

        grecaptcha.ready(function() {
            grecaptcha.execute(clientId, {
                    action: 'submit'
                })
                .then(function(token) {
                    document.getElementById("@Html.IdFor(m => Model.Value)").value = token;
                });
        });
    }
       var hiddenField = document.getElementById(@Html.Raw("\"" + Html.IdFor(m => Model.Value) + "\""));
        var parent = hiddenField.parentNode;
        if (parent.classList.contains("sc-formdesign-fieldcontainer")) {
            var textDiv = document.createElement("div");
            textDiv.innerHTML = "(ReCaptcha V3 Hidden Field)";
            parent.appendChild(textDiv);
    }

    var expCallback = function () {
    debugger;
        grecaptcha.reset(clientId);
    };
</script>



public override ValidationResult Validate(object value)
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage);
            }
            var isCaptchaValid = ValidateCaptcha((string)value, this.SecretKey);
            if (!isCaptchaValid)
            {
                return new ValidationResult(this.FormatMessage(new object[] { this.Title }));
            }
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
        public static bool ValidateCaptcha(string response, string secret)
        {
            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
         
            var res = httpClient.GetAsync(Settings.GetSetting("recaptchaverifyurl") + secret + "&response=" + response + "").Result;

            if (res.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                return false;

            string JSONres = res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            dynamic JSONdata = JObject.Parse(JSONres);

            if (JSONdata.success != "true")
                return false;

            return true;
        }
```

Comment: Can anybody suggest me?